# How to inject dependencies into a custom UserNamePasswordValidator in WCF?

Tags: wcf, security, dependency-injection, unity-container, ioc-container

I'm using a UserNamePasswordValidator in WCF along with Unity for my dependency injection, but since WCF creates the instance of the UserNamePasswordValidator, I cannot inject my container into the class.  So how would one go about this?

The simplest solution I can think of is to create a static proxy/wrapper class around a static instance of a UnityContainer, which exposes all the same methods... This way, any class can access the container, and I don't need to inject it everywhere.

So I could just do UnityContainerWrapper.Resolve() anywhere in code.  So basically this solution solves 2 problems for me, I can use it in classes that I'm not creating an instance of, and I can use it anywhere without having to inject the container into a bunch of classes.

The only downside I can think of is that I'm now potentially exposing my container to a bunch of classes that wouldn't of had access to the container before.  Not really sure if this is even a problem though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this downsite is realy bad, and you should avoid it. In your case you can do something like this

```
public class CustomUserNameValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
    {
        public static CustomUserNameValidator Current {
            get; private set;
        }

        public CustomUserNameValidator() {
            Current = this;
        }

        public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
        {
            throw new FaultException("No pasaran");

        }

        [Dependency]
        public ISomeService Service {
            get; set;
        }
    }
```

It will be created only once for service when service host is created, so you should write following code

```
 using (ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(CalculatorService))) //here it will be created
            {
                container.BuildUp(CustomUserNameValidator.Current); //here you can inject all you need
             }
```

This is just inverted idea with static wrapper of the unity container :)

Comment: I'm hosting through IIS, so I'm guessing I could do the BuildUp in the constructor of the service contract.  But there's still a downside to this as well, you have to publically expose your service... But I guess that's a lot better than exposing the entire container.

Comment: On another note... Since I'm using a config file to map all my objects for Unity, is my original static idea still a concern?

Assume I don't use a static wrapper class around a unity container instance, I could still create a new UnityContainer anywhere in code and configure it using the config file and create any objects I wanted.  So I'm not sure the UnityContainerWrapper idea is even creating an "issue", it's just making an existing issue more noticable?  If that makes sense...

Comment: probably, you have several assemblies, but only one is Unity aware - the most highlevel, so other can't create unitycontainer at all.
Second thing is lifetime management. I's realy a big risc to create two containers with singletons, becouse you can get the whole other behaviour then you expect. So this is sort of conventional things, but it make such a scenario very unlikable.

Comment: I do agree, having just one assembly unity-aware would be nice... But in reality, aren't none of them?... Unless you're using strictly constructor injection?  Because you have to tag all your dependencies with the [Dependency] attribute... So you have to reference the Unity assemblies anyway?  Thoughts?